# Why use None for the batch dimension in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code, the `None` is used to declare the size of the placeholders.

```
x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, max_sequence_length]) 
y_output = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
```

As I know, this `None` is used to specify a variable batch dimension. But, in each code, we have a variable that shows the batch size, such as:

```
batch_size = 250
```

So, is there any reason to use `None` in such cases instead of simply declaring the placeholders as?

```
x_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, max_sequence_length]) 
y_output = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size])
```

Comment: So that you can predict ALL your test samples at once, or even one bye one. Otherwise the input to the network would always have to be fixed size batches.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Thanks! Seems reasonable. I would like to accept it if you post as an answer.

Comment: Added with few more comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just so that the input of the network doesn't get bounded to a fixed-sized batches, and you can later reuse the learnt network to predict either single instances or arbitrarily long batches (e.g. predict all your test samples at once).

In other words, it doesn't do much during training, as batches are usually of a fixed size during tranning anyway, but it makes the network more useful when testing.

Comment: As a complementary comment, our final batch during training may have a fewer number of elements than `batch_size`, so it can be also useful during training.

Comment: @Hossein Sure! In sone applications batches are automatically generated through data augmentation or randomly looping, so all the batches would always have the same size. But in single-pass approaches the last batch will certainly have different size! Nice for pointing out.